# javascript sode for mouse position display and Geolocation with openlayer and geocodezip example

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

I want to combine Geolocation and Mouse Position Display (lng/lat; outside of map)from the Openlayer and geocodezip site.I tried various combinations of codes But only the Mouse Position Display (lng/lat; outside of map) is correct.Geolocation does not work.In fact, both of them do not work together. This is the code I've tested the last time.
please guide me.Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mouse Position and Geolocation</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="mouse-position"></div>
    <form>
      <label>Projection </label>
      <select id="projection">
        <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
        <option value="EPSG:3857">EPSG:3857</option>
      </select>
      <label>Precision </label>
      <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="6"/>
    </form>
 <div id="info" style="display: none;"></div>
    <label for="track">
      track position
      <input id="track" type="checkbox"/>
    </label>
    <p>
 positionshowingtouser: <code id="positionshowingtouser1"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      position accuracy : <code id="accuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      altitude : <code id="altitude"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      altitude accuracy : <code id="altitudeAccuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      heading : <code id="heading"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      speed : <code id="speed"></code>
   resultTEST : <code id="resultTEST"></code>
    </p>
    <script>
      var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(6),
        //projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
        // be placed within the map.
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: true
          }
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
      projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target.value);
      });

      var precisionInput = document.getElementById('precision');
      precisionInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var format = ol.coordinate.createStringXY(event.target.valueAsNumber);
        mousePositionControl.setCoordinateFormat(format);
      });
   var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
        trackingOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        projection: view.getProjection()
      });

      function el(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
      }

      el('track').addEventListener('change', function() {// addEventListener yek method javascripty koli ast
        geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);// setTracking yek method openlayeri ast ke meghdar boolian migirad
      });

      // update the HTML page when the position changes.
      geolocation.on('change', function() {
     el('positionshowingtouser1').innerText = geolocation.getPosition();
        el('accuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAccuracy() + ' [m]';
        el('altitude').innerText = geolocation.getAltitude() + ' [m]';
        el('altitudeAccuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAltitudeAccuracy() + ' [m]';
        el('heading').innerText = geolocation.getHeading() + ' [rad]';
        el('speed').innerText = geolocation.getSpeed() + ' [m/s]'; 
  
      });

      // handle geolocation error.
      geolocation.on('error', function(error) {
        var info = document.getElementById('info');
        info.innerHTML = error.message;
        info.style.display = '';
      });

      var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();
      geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function() {
        accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
      });

      var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();
      positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 16,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#FF0000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      }));

      geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
        var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
        positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
          new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
      });

      new ol.layer.Vector({
        map: map,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature]
        })
      });
  
    </script>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your code "Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined". In line `projection: view.getProjection()` the variable `view` is not defined.

Not sure if `view` needs to be a global variable but if you define it outside the function then the location API is consumed. Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/sneyxcu6/)

```js
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(6),
  //projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
  undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: true
    }
  }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});

var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target.value);
});

var precisionInput = document.getElementById('precision');
precisionInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var format = ol.coordinate.createStringXY(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  mousePositionControl.setCoordinateFormat(format);
});
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
  // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
  trackingOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  },
  projection: view.getProjection()
});

function el(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

el('track').addEventListener('change', function() { // addEventListener yek method javascripty koli ast
  geolocation.setTracking(this.checked); // setTracking yek method openlayeri ast ke meghdar boolian migirad
});

// update the HTML page when the position changes.
geolocation.on('change', function() {
  el('positionshowingtouser1').innerText = geolocation.getPosition();
  el('accuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAccuracy() + ' [m]';
  el('altitude').innerText = geolocation.getAltitude() + ' [m]';
  el('altitudeAccuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAltitudeAccuracy() + ' [m]';
  el('heading').innerText = geolocation.getHeading() + ' [rad]';
  el('speed').innerText = geolocation.getSpeed() + ' [m/s]';

});

// handle geolocation error.
geolocation.on('error', function(error) {
  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  info.innerHTML = error.message;
  info.style.display = '';
});

var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();
geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function() {
  accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
});

var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();
positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 16,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#FF0000'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 2
    })
  })
}));

geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
  var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
  positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
    new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
});

new ol.layer.Vector({
  map: map,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature]
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>


<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="mouse-position"></div>
<form>
  <label>Projection </label>
  <select id="projection">
    <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
    <option value="EPSG:3857">EPSG:3857</option>
  </select>
  <label>Precision </label>
  <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="6" />
</form>
<div id="info" style="display: none;"></div>
<label for="track">
      track position
      <input id="track" type="checkbox"/>
    </label>
<p>
  positionshowingtouser: <code id="positionshowingtouser1"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp; position accuracy : <code id="accuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp; altitude : <code id="altitude"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp; altitude accuracy : <code id="altitudeAccuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  heading : <code id="heading"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp; speed : <code id="speed"></code> resultTEST : <code id="resultTEST"></code>
</p>
```